# AngularJS Angular-Route on Ubuntu changing routes /#/ -> /#!/ links not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ubuntu, angular-routing

Project works fine locally.
However after deploying it to an AWS Ubuntu instance, the routing does not seem to be working.
The home page of, www.lewisengelart.com/#/ loads with a bang as, www.lewisengelart.com/#!/
and if you try a link, the browser attempts to load
www.lewisengelart.com/#!/#%2Fabout rather than
www.lewisengelart.com/#/about.

Once again, this project works fine locally, I cannot figure out what is tripping it up on the ubuntu instance.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Here is app.js, the route config

```
var app = angular.module("App", ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(
    function($q, $location) {
    return {
        'responseError':function(rejection){
        if (rejection.status == 401){
            $location.url('/letmein');
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
    };
});
$routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html'
    })
    .when('/text',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/text.html',
        controller: 'textCtrl'
    })
    .when('/magnet',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/magnet.html',
        // controller: 'magnetCtrl'
    })
    .when('/gauge',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/gauge.html',
        // controller: 'gaugeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/animation',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/animation.html',
        controller: 'animationCtrl as ACtrl'
    })
    .when('/about',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
    })
    .when('/contact',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/Contact.html',
    })


    .when('/letmein',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/loginReg.html',
        controller: 'adminCtrl'
    })
    .when('/add',{
        templateUrl: 'partials/add.html',
        controller: 'workCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}])
```

And the home page partial with links

```
<div class="indexHeader col-md-3">
 <a href="/#/"><h1>Lewis Engel</h1></a>

<div class="worksBox">
  <a ng-href="/#/about"><span class="colorFive">About</span></a>
  <a href="/#/contact"><span class="colorSix">Contact</span></a>

  <a href="/#/text"><span class="colorOne">Emergent Possibilities</span></a>
  <a href="/#/animation"><span class="colorTwo">Emergence over Time</span></a>
  <a href="/#/magnet"><span class="colorThree">Magnetic Attractions</span></a>
  <a href="/#/gauge"><span class="colorFour">Meaningless Measures</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: ahhh, I figured out that it is something with the version of angular, angular-route and angular-animate. The local version is still running angular 1.5.8. While the deployed version got the newer 1.6.0.

Comment: Problem solved, just in case anyone else fumbles on this. Per angular documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8. Have to add $locationProvider and $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); -- to override a new protocol in the updated version of Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Per angular documentation.

docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8.

Have to add

```
$locationProvider
```

and

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

to override a new protocol in the updated version of Angular.